# Как узнать размер входящего пакета UDP от сервера?

Tags: c++builder, c++

Для затравки - компонента Indy - IdUDPClient. В скором времени планирую переписать под API, но тем не менее, даже быстрое гугление по АПИ сокетов не подсказало, как можно узнать длину входного пакета.

Правда просматривая сниффером входящие пакеты, понял, что в первых 20-ти байтах содержится информация об этом пакете, в т.ч. и его длина, но я не знаю, как распарсить его. Подскажите?

Comment: IdUDPClient->ReceiveBuffer()??? Не? Один из параметров - размер буфера.

Comment: Нуу... этот параметр же сам указываешь, следовательно наугад - не то, что требуется.

Comment: Что значит сам указываешь? Вы получаете буфер, и его размер.

Comment: У меня в программе так это выглядит:
    Sysutils::TBytes ReceiveBuff;  
ReceiveBuff.set_length(1000);  
 
char *gstats = "\xff\xff\xff\xff getstatus";
IdUDPClient1->SendBuffer(RawToBytes(gstats,strlen(gstats)));
IdUDPClient1->ReceiveBuffer(ReceiveBuff, 500); //тут принимаем буфер ЗА ВРЕМЯ, указаное вторым параметром.
Сейчас гляну в билдере, может, функции еще параметры можно какие скормить, хотя если есть функция получения размера входного пакета, то это отлично.

Comment: Кстати это решение я нашел в инете, и у меня очень много привязано к этому TBytes ReceiveBuff, что, как мне кажется, не очень хорошо, и как-то можно обойтись без этого, но как - не знаю. Поэтому вообще хочу отказаться от инди и переделать на АПИшные виндовые функции. Заодно лучше понять сокеты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В recvfrom(sock, buf, bufsize, flags, &from, &fromlen) просим большое число (bufsize) (в большой буфер). Большой - значит больше, чем максимально возможный UDP пакет. Вернет длину очередного пакета и поместит его в буфер. В from и fromlen вернет адрес сервера (IP:Port) и длину этого адреса (ну для IP это не интересно). Подробнее  man 2 recvfrom. В принципе, в винде д.б. очень похоже.

Comment: В моём случае задается буфер, далее посылается команда серверу, приходит ответ в виде пакета, и помещается в буфер. И в итоге у меня получается информация, пришедшая с сервера + мусор для забивки буфера. 
Правда единственное - странно то, что этот якобы "мусор" всё время в виде одних и тех же символов.

Comment: И странно еще другое - у меня отправка и прием стоит по таймеру, и вот первый раз в буфере находится инфа с мусором, а последующие уже всё нормально... Может, я чего-то где-то упустил?!

Comment: Используйте сокеты (C или C++)

Comment: Похоже, так и сделаю.